# How to correctly storage registers in an FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I need to write in VHDL a program that initialize a sensor registers using i2c. My problem is to write an efficent program that don't waste all FPGA space. The number of registers I need to storage are 400 register composed by 8bit address and 8 bit data.

Program I write is:

```
entity i2cReg is
    port (
            RegSel : in std_logic;
            Address : out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
            Data : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
            RegStop : out std_logic;
            ModuleEN : in std_logic
    );
end i2cReg;

architecture i2cReg_archi of i2cReg is
    signal counter :integer := 0;

    begin
        process(RegSel, ModuleEN)
        begin
            if ModuleEN = '0' then
                    Address <= x"10";  
                    Data <= x"10";
                    RegStop <= '0';
                    counter <= 0;
            elsif rising_edge(RegSel) then
                counter <= counter + 1;
                case counter is
                    when 0 =>
                     Address <= x"10";
                     Data <= x"10";
                    when 1 =>
                     Address <= x"10";
                     Data <= x"10";
                    when 2 =>
                     Address <= x"10";
                     Data <= x"10";
                    when 3 =>
                     Address <= x"10";
                     Data <= x"10";
                    when 4 =>
                     Address <= x"10";
                     Data <= x"10";
                    when 5 =>
                     Address <= x"10";
                     Data <= x"10";
                    when 400 =>
                        RegStop <= '1';
                    when others =>
                end case;
            end if;
        end process;

end i2cReg_archi;
```

There is a way to optimize this code? Or you advice me to use an external eeprom?

Comment: If the FPGA is a type with a BlockRam primitive, then yes, there is a way to optimise this code.

Comment: FPGAs have thousends of registers, so using 400 is not a number ... BUT you are correct to ask for a cheaper solution. Most FPGA have embedded RAMs of several kBytes. Some other FPGAs can use there LUTs as RAM which are good to store data <1 KByte. What is your target architectur ?

Comment: I've seen, as you said, some FPGA have embedded RAM. But I need to storage this amout of data in device and not to write RAM when I power on the device. Is possible use this memory space as permanent storage an write it when I program the device?

Comment: So this is 400 pairs of 8-bit registers rather than 400 small memories of 256 bytes each? At the gate&FF level, 8+8 400-bit shift registers might be the way to go, with FPGAs, block RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaro - you have not mentioned the FPGA vendor or the device but the answer is: Yes, you can initialize ROM in an FPGA so that the values you need are present after configuration. Both Altera and Xilinx allow you to provide a file with the initial values during synthesis.

Kevin.

Comment: Just to comment (or add) on to this answer (because I think it is the right one), if the registers on the FPGA need to be editable (or change during run time), I would recommend using a block RAM.  It will allow you to greatly simplify your design and reduce the logic used to produce this register map.

Answer (score 0):

Initialized BlockRAM is in general the correct solution if you are on Xilinx or Altera.

But there are exceptions where a logic implementation can also work:
For example, if the content of your 400 registers has repeating patterns or many registers with the same value (like in your example code). In this case, if you implement it as logic, your synthesis tool will optimize it heavily. You may actually end up with a very small amount of logic if the register content is very repeating. It is sometimes also possible to improve the optimization by clever reordering of the registers.

100-200 logic cells is often considered "cheaper" than a BlockRAM. But it depends mostly on which resource is most scarce in your particular application.

Regardless if you go for initialized BlockRAM or logic, I would suggest that you model it as an array of std_logic_vector instead of using case/when.
The "array of std_logic_vector" approach is platform independent, and can be synthesized to either BlockRAM or logic. Your synthesis tool will usually try to automatically select the best implementation. But you can also force the sythesis tool to use either logic or BlockRAM by using vendor specific attributes. (I can't tell you which attributes to use, since I don't know which platform you are using)

Example:

```
type REG_TYPE is array (0 to 3) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
constant REGISTERS : REG_TYPE :=
    (x"0000",
     x"0001",
     x"0010",
     x"0100");
```

And in your process, something like:

```
if rising_edge(RegSel) then
    Address <= REGISTERS( counter )(15 downto 8);
    Data    <= REGISTERS( counter )( 7 downto 0);
end if;
```